# Group two tables in one query

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Is there any possible way to select and group two tables in the same time?

My query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.estimated_sum_all, t1.story_point_sum_all, 
 t1.time_spent, t2.id, t2.time_spent FROM
 burndown_snap_all t1, status_history_hours t2 WHERE t1.project_id = 72 
 AND t2.project_id = 72 group by t1.id
```

Results:

[image]

The problem is that I would like to group also the second table ((status_history_hours)) to get a proper results in one query.

Samples:

I have two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM `burndown_snap_all` WHERE project_id=72
```

Results:
[image]

```
SELECT * FROM `status_history_hours` WHERE project_id=72
```

results:

[image]

What I wanna to do is to join the second column to the result (time_spent)

Comment: what do you mean with  "I would like to group"  ?  your need  a sum ..or  a count .?.  show also a proper data samples please

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can group all the tables you need

But group by is used  for aggregation function eg sum() or count()  so you could

```
SELECT 
    t1.id
    , t1.estimated_sum_all
    , t1.story_point_sum_all
    , sum(t1.time_spent)
    , t2.id
    , sum(t2.time_spent ) 
FROM  burndown_snap_all t1
INNER JOIN status_history_hours t2 ON  t1.project_id = 72  AND t2.project_id = t1.project_id
group by t1.id  , t1.estimated_sum_all , t1.story_point_sum_all , t2.id
```

otherwise if don't need  aggreagtion fynction and you need  avoid duplicated value you should use distinct and not group

```
SELECT disticnt 
    t1.id
    , t1.estimated_sum_all
    , t1.story_point_sum_all
    , t1.time_spent
    , t2.id
    , t2.time_spent 
FROM  burndown_snap_all t1
INNER JOIN status_history_hours t2 ON  t1.project_id = 72  AND t2.project_id = t1.project_id
```